# _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC - How To Exclude Stack Objects

Tags: c++, debugging, memory

In MSVS c++, I enable memory leak detection with:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
```

If I create an object (of a custom class), that is created on the stack, I get output like:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{84} normal block at 0x00BBA448, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <$|      > 24 7C BB 00 00 00 00 00
```

Which makes sense, because the allocation is held until the end of the application. It is not a memory leak.

If I use NEW and DELETE with the same object, there is no 'memory leak.'

```
MyClass* MyObjectPointer = new MyClass();
delete MyObjectPointer;
```

My question is, can I unallocate the objects that are created on the stack, before the application ends, so the memory leak detection will not show them? You can't DELETE them.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try enclosing the object in its own scope, e.g. `{ MyClass MyObject; ... }`

Comment: Change the scope, thank you for the tip. I changed the code so that Main() calls another function, which does the actual work.